.NET 8 Hangfire application on IIS is not always running
I have a Hangfire application written on .NET 8 and hosted on IIS. It's used to run a daily scheduled job.
Problem is that after some time the application shuts down and does not start again, so job does not run.
I did everything in the Hangfire documentation section "If nothing works for you…, but it still does not work. I recycle the app pool / restart, but application does not start again.
IIS:
installed Application Initialization module

application pool:
set .NET CLR version to 4.0
set managed pipeline mode to 4.0
set start mode to AlwaysRunning
set Idle Time-Out (minutes) to 0

site:
set Preload Enabled to true
Configuration Manager → system.webServer/applicationInitialization
From: ApplicationHost.config
set doAppInitAfterRestart to True
added hostName and initializationPage to Collection Editor

What am I missing?
Windows Server 2019, IIS version 10.

You shouldn’t use Hangfire from the first place.

Are there any error messages or logs? You need to get some information to narrow down the problem.

@LexLi thank you for the most useless reply ever.

@XudongPeng hello, no, there are no errors, it just doesn't work.

Not sure if it is related to the Core version, maybe you can try .NET 6/7. Or the windows service mentioned by the community below to achieve your needs.

You should host your hangfire server in different application - windows service for example. And use Web API just to host hangfire dashboard.
Setup would look something like this:
For Windows service:
    var hostbuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    var host = hostbuilder.UseWindowsService().
    ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => 
    {
       var storageOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
     {
         CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
         SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
         QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
         UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
         DisableGlobalLocks = true,
         EnableHeavyMigrations = true,
     };
      services.AddHangfire(c => c
         .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
         .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
         .UseSqlServerStorage(() => new SqlConnection(connectionString), storageOptions));
    
    services.AddHangfireServer(a =>
    {
        a.WorkerCount = Math.Min(Environment.ProcessorCount * hangfireConfiguration.WorkerCount, 10);
        a.Queues = new[] { "default", "lowprio" };
    });
    
    }).Build();

await host.RunAsync();

And for the Web API you just configure the Hangfire dashboard , use the same code from above just without adding the hangfire servers.
Something like this:
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
          var storageOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
             {
                 CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                 SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                 QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                 UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                 PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = false
             };
        builder.Services..AddHangfire(c => c
                 .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                 .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                 .UseSqlServerStorage(() => new SqlConnection(connectionString), storageOptions));
        
        var app = builder.Build();
        
        var hangfireStorage = new SqlServerStorage(() => new SqlConnection(connectionString), storageOptions);
        var dashboardOptions = new DashboardOptions { Authorization = new[] { new AllowAllAuthorizationFilter() } };
        
        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/dashboard", dashboardOptions, hangfireStorage);
    await app.RunAsync();
}

    public class AllowAllAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

PS Don't forget to use same connection string. Your server and your dashboard will look into the same database.
Achieving always on on IIS is really challenging and depends on a lot of things - this way is much easier - widows service is always running.

Sadly the Hangfire developers didn’t make such information obvious from their documentation.

So I should host the server as a Windows service and the dashboard as an IIS web app? And I'm guessing all of the jobs and logic will be in Server application while the Dashboard application will only hold Program.cs or something.

Something like that - yes.

Hey, wanted to update you. I got it working. Split the solution into two projects - dashboard and server. It took a whole day to get it to work, mainly had to reconfigure Program.cs, but it's working. I wish Hangfire developers would have their documentation up-to-date. Thank you.

Nice - glad that I could help :)

Another update. Apparently Microsoft changed something in .NET 7 or 8, not sure exactly, but now DefaultHostBuilder first reads environment variables prefixed with "DOTNET_". I couldn't figure out why my windows service kept seeing Development/Test environments as Production, so this is the reason why.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#default-builder-settings-1
So if anyone else is having trouble with your application seeing wrong hosting environment - make sure you have the enviroment variable DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT set
